# Create timeline chart based on annual data

Tags: charts, google-sheets, spreadsheet

How does one automatically create a continuous chart over time based on data that is only available as each year?

For example, most data comes in the form of the following:

```
         j | f | m | a | m | j | j | a | s | o | n | d | 
year 1   x   y
year 2           z
year 3
```

However, in order to create a chart than spans multiple years, I need the data transposed and combined  as below:

```
year 1 | j  x
       | f  y
       | m 
       | a
       | m
       | j
       | j
       | a 
       | s 
       | o
       | n
       | d
year 2 | j
       | f
       | m  z
       | a
       | m
       | j
       | j
       | a 
       | s 
       | o
       | n
       | d
year 3 | j
       | f
       | m 
       | a
       | m
       | j
       | j
       | a 
       | s 
       | o
       | n
       | d
```

Is there a simple way to do this with pivot tables or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in Sheet1. In Sheet2 A2 put this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ArrayFormula(JOIN(" , , , , , , , , , , , ,",FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet1!A2:A <> ""))),","))
```

In Sheet2 B2 put:

=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(rept(join(",",transpose(Sheet1!B1:N1)),countA(Sheet1!A2:A)),",")))

These will expand if years are added.
To get the data, this will work, however, a query will need to be added for each additional year:

```
=transpose({query(Sheet1!B2:M2,"select *"),query(Sheet1!B3:M3,"select *"),query(Sheet1!B4:M4,"select *")})
```

Comment: While this technically works, I should have been more explicit in that I also need the data values for each year and month.

Comment: @skube I added a way to get the data to my answer.